# Recordset Subtotals in Subform

Tags: ms-access

I have to update a recordset that holds the following type of data:

```
Order# - OrderQty - TotalQty
1000   -    10    - <blank>
2000   -    20    - <blank>
1000   -    15    - <blank>
3000   -    40    - <blank>
```

After code runs the recordset should look like this:

```
Order# - OrderQty - TotalQty
1000   -    10    -    25
2000   -    20    -    10
1000   -    15    -    25
3000   -    40    -    40
```

I am not sure how to approach this, since insertions and deletions and "Order#" changes have to be taken into account as well. I think the code should be in the "After Update" and "After Delete Confirm" events. Besides that I am not sure how to proceed with the code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below query.

```
UPDATE tblOrders SET TotalQty=DSum("OrderQty","tblOrders","Order=" & tblOrders.Order);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks that works. Is there a reason we would not use recordsets for this?

Comment: No reason. I have just used this method but you can use any method to work. If this solve your problem then please accept the answer. Tick mark the answer.